# Entity Framework conversion of data type (Data mapping)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

If I have a dictionary,

```
e.g. var results = (IDictionary<string, object>)fb.Get("me");
```

And that dictionary contains primitives, arrays and dictionaries of data can it be passed as a model directly? How does one override a mapping of a particular entry, say I want the date to be stored as a string formatted in a certain way.

Atm I'm doing the custom mapping in the Controller, but that has already started to become messy having all parsing code in the one place.

The alternative is I pass the dictionary in to the constructor of the model, and do the class specific parsing there..

Comment: Can you provide more information? maybe examples of the concept. It's hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish only from the explanation and a single line of code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class for the parsing logic rather than complicate your controller or your model. This parsing service class would contain all the messy parsing logic. This will keep your controller and model much cleaner.

```
var parsingService = new ParsingService(tb.Get("me"));
var model = parsingService.GetModel();
```